# Wi-Fi speed on my laptop with RTL8723DE is a bit slow and its range is also very low, what to do?

Tags: networking, wireless, realtek-wireless

My Wi-Fi connection seems to be very weak and the range is very low. It drops by two bars if I just move to the next room and by two if just step outside.

The speed is also not fast as compared to what I get from the router on my desktop .

My laptop is a HP laptop with *RTL8723de* module. Can anyone help me in bumping up my Wi-Fi speed?

Result of `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:d723]
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8319]
Kernel driver in use: rtl8723de
Kernel modules: rtl8723de
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quite often, the weak signal is a symptom of the antenna wire being connected to connection #1 on the card when the default driver is expecting to see the signal at connection #2. Of course, you could open the laptop and switch the wire or you could try a driver parameter that permits antenna selection at the driver level.

From the terminal:

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723de
sudo modprobe rtl8723de ant_sel=2
```

Any improvement? If so, we'll write one conf file and make it permanent.

If there is no improvement, try the sequence again with `ant_sel=1`and report the result.

**EDIT**: Since you have determined that 2 is helpful, create a file that will make the parameter permanent:

```
sudo -i
echo "options rtl8723de ant_sel=2"  >  /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723de.conf
exit
```

You should be all set.

Comment: Yeah dude its better now and the range has also increased.
Will the above setting be lost as soon as i switch off my laptop??@chili555

Comment: It *will* be lost unless we write a quick one line conf file. Is it better with 2 or 1? I shall edit my answer to give the procedure once we know which it is.

Comment: When i typed this command:
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723de
sudo modprobe rtl8723de ant_sel=2 . 
It became better.

Comment: See my edit above in a few moments.

Comment: I had the same issue, and this answer fixes it! But now I cannot connect my Bluetooth headset : https://askubuntu.com/q/1393799/1171035