# How can I install rtl8723de driver

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, realtek-wireless

I have tried various methods to install WiFi drivers on my machine. I have downloaded the `rtl_wifi` directory and have installed the necessary firmware too. However, when I run the command:

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723de
```

and

```
sudo modprobe rtl8723de
```

I am getting this as output:

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'rtl8723de': Operation not permitted
```

Please help me find a solution to this as I am a student and need WiFi on my machine almost daily.

Comment: See the 'note' at the end of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1018851/480481). Also https://askubuntu.com/q/1037323/480481