# Cannot connect Bluetooth headset after fixing WiFi issue: Unable to get Headset Voice gateway SDP record: Host is down

Tags: drivers, wireless, bluetooth, headset

My Bluetooth headset was working fine, but my WiFi did not.
I fixed the WiFi issue following https://askubuntu.com/a/1037813/1171035, by doing this command:

```
echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=2"  >  /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

But now I cannot connect my Bluetooth headset.
It appears in the Bluetooth settings of Gnome, but when I click on `connect` I see the loading logo and then it stops, and the headset is not connected.

Checking with `systemctl status bluetooth.service` gives this log message:

```
bluetoothd[855]: Unable to get Headset Voice gateway SDP record: Host is down
```

How can I solve both the WiFi and Bluetooth issues?

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.3.